# google actions account linking custom response

Tags: actions-on-google

When linking to a google account inside a google actions, the code to use in actions sdk (as per documentation) is:

`conv.ask(new SignIn('To get your account details'));`

What the system seems to do is, prefix the above text to a standard text. The response for the above code seems to be:

`To get your account details, you'll need  ... profile picture?`

Is there a way to customise the rest of the response body? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no way to customize the entire message. While you can provide a preamble, the rest is standardized for consistency.

Comment: Thanks @Nick Felker for confirming that